# Background video Parallax effect without JS

Tags: html, css

With images you only have to use:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Is there a way to achieve the parallax effect with videos without the use of JS?

Link to my example site for reference:
https://captain-stoves-76350.netlify.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,

Set your video div to:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
```

Then add a wrapper div around the rest of your content and do:

```
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
```

Then add padding to your body dependent on the height of your video:

```
padding-top: 500px;
```

**Note:** this will only work if your video is at the top of the page, but you can play around with the `top: x;` value if you need it further down, just make sure that the rest of your content is inside your wrapper and the z-index is set higher than your video div.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful.

Comment: No problem, also just realised if you move your video further down the page, it won't be visible as the content wrapper will cover it, so you'd need to have a content wrapper around your content, then the video div, then another content wrapper (both with `z-index: 1` or higher)